# ArcPy Export SQL Server to Shapefile gives RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, sql-server, export

I have executed a stored procedure and want to export this layer to a shapefile.  I feel like this should be an easy solution.  I tried using arcpy.CopyFeatures_management and it threw an error.  I am not sure if CopyFeature is meant for sql server tables.

I am running ArcGIS 10.1.  I am using SQL server 2012 with geography data type.  The table is not registered with the geodatabase.  The error is below:

```
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
```

Below is my code:

```
import pyodbc
import arcpy

sqlserver = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=sqlserver;DATABASE=AndrewSandbox;Integrated Security=True')
cursor = sqlserver.cursor()
table = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM TEMPLINE")

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(table, "D:\Python\WaterSage\Viability\TestExport.shp")
```

Comment: Please give more information. What error did it throw? CopyFeatures_management should work fine for SQL Server.

Comment: Please update the question to include the version of ArcGIS in use, the geometry storage type, the SQL-Server version, whether the table is registered with the geodatabase, and the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have an SQL Server table available to test this, but I was surprised to see you using `pyodbc` in this workflow.

I recommend that you try to use a [Query Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_query_layer/00s50000000n000000/):

> A query layer is a layer or stand-alone table that is defined by a SQL
>   query.

...

> [You can persist a query layer by exporting it to a feature class.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Exporting_a_query_layer/00s500000060000000/)